# Translating mod_rewrite rules to IIS URL Rewrite on Plesk hosting

Tags: php, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I want to rewrite the following URL

```
http://dramatainment.com/dramas.php?id=000020&channel=HUM%20TV
```

to look like this

```
http://dramatainment.com/dramas/000020/HUM-TV/
```

Here is the code from my `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^dramas/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ dramas.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^dramas/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

My code works for me on localhost but not online. The reason is that I have hosted a PHP website on Windows Hosting (Plesk) on Godaddy. It is shared hosting. Godaddy's online support blogs reveal that mod_rewrite does not work on windows hosting. We need to use Microsoft's URL rewrite module. I have no idea how do I use it with my PHP website. Can anyone please show me how to do it?

Comment: If you are using windows hosting, then you need to use URL Rewrite. You can use .htaccess on windows hosting. My recommendation you can ask to them to change your account to linux platform if you insist using mod_rewrite.

Comment: I really don't insist on doing that, can you guide me on how i can use URL Rewrite without .htaccess ? I have no idea really

Comment: Please refer to https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx